# New column to get the previous date for a certain category (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-manipulation

I'm trying to create a certain prediction model. I decided to do the entire data manipulation with
python this time instead of with DAX (pbi) to learn python.

I have 2 columns that are relevant for this question : Customer and Date.
Each row is an invoice created for that customer at that certain date.

I'm trying for each row (invoice) to get the previous invoice date. It is important to understand
that the new column must take in consideration the customer, that means that for each customer's invoice i want to get the previous date of invoice.

This is how it looks like :

```
data = [['A', 17/07/2020], ['B', 15/07/2020], ['C', 14/07/2020], ['C', 10/07/2020], ['B', 09/07/2020]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Customer', 'Date'])
print(df)

Customer Date
A        17/07/2020
B        15/07/2020
C        14/07/2020
C        10/07/2020
B        09/07/2020
```

This is the result i seek :

```
Customer Date        PrevInvoiceDate
A        17/07/2020  NaT
B        15/07/2020  09/07/2020
C        14/07/2020  10/07/2020
C        10/07/2020  NaT
B        09/07/2020  NaT
```

I tried to use pandas' shift, loc, filter etc.. but with no luck,
I would be grateful to learn the right way to do this kind of manipulation and learn from you all.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['A', '17/07/2020'], ['B', '15/07/2020'], ['C', '14/07/2020'], ['C', '10/07/2020'], ['B', '09/07/2020']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Customer', 'Date'])
df=df.sort_values(by=['Customer','Date'])
df['test']=df.groupby('Customer')['Date'].shift()
print(df)
  Customer        Date        test
0        A  17/07/2020         NaN
4        B  09/07/2020         NaN
1        B  15/07/2020  09/07/2020
3        C  10/07/2020         NaN
2        C  14/07/2020  10/07/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, looks like your `Date` column is of type string rather than datetime. Let's convert it to datetime. Then, sort the dataframe by `Date`.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values('Date')

# Output:
Customer    Date
0   A   17/07/2020
1   B   15/07/2020
2   C   14/07/2020
3   C   10/07/2020
4   B   09/07/2020
```

Then, group the dataframe by `Customer`, then use `apply()` function. For each group (all invoices of a specific customer), shift the `Date` column by 1.

```
df['PrevInvoiceDate'] = df.groupby('Customer')['Date'].shift(periods=1)

# Output:
Customer    Date    PrevInvoiceDate
2   C   2020-07-14  NaT
1   B   2020-07-15  NaT
0   A   2020-07-17  NaT
4   B   2020-09-07  2020-07-15
3   C   2020-10-07  2020-07-14
```

Also, the function `shift()` will shift the column values towards down by 1 by default, so you can get rid of `periods=1`. Here I just have it to make sure you understand what it does.

Finally, if you want your original date format back, we can convert the datetime back to string.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['PrevInvoiceDate'] = df['PrevInvoiceDate'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

df.sort_index()  # (Optional) Sort the dataframe by its original index

# Output:
    Customer    Date    PrevInvoiceDate
0   A   17/07/2020  NaN
1   B   15/07/2020  NaN
2   C   14/07/2020  NaN
3   C   07/10/2020  14/07/2020
4   B   07/09/2020  15/07/2020
```

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what i needed, 
but this is very useful for cases i need to get the opposite of what i needed this time.
Thank you.

Comment: @DanielMillionshik, unfortunately I didn't notice that I sort the dataframe in the opposite way. However, just want to point out that the method you accepted is not safe. It sorted the dataframe before converting the date string to date object, which may potentially give you wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

This is a curly one. One way would be `left merge df` with a `groupby` results that picks the  last previous in each group using apply. Select the indices of duplicated and null them

```
     import numpy as np
df2=df.merge(df.groupby('Customer')['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1:]).\
             reset_index().rename(columns={'Date':'PrevInvoiceDate'}),\
             how='left',on='Customer').drop(columns=['level_1'])

df2.loc[df2.loc[df2["PrevInvoiceDate"].duplicated('first')].\
        index,'PrevInvoiceDate']=np.nan



     Customer        Date      PrevInvoiceDate
0        A       17/07/2020             NaN
1        B       15/07/2020      09/07/2020
2        C       14/07/2020      10/07/2020
3        C       10/07/2020             NaN
4        B       09/07/2020             NaN
```

Comment: That works, but there is an easier way to do this.
I will use this to other cases though, thank you.